# How to rotate the 3D scatter plots in google colaboratory?

Tags: python, data-visualization, scatter-plot, google-colaboratory, scatter3d

I am generating a 3d scatter plot in google colab, but the problem is that the generated fig is static and is not rotatable.
I also tried the command

%matplotlib notebook

to enable the 3D scatter rotation as it apparently work in jupyter notebook environment,but it seems this doesn't work in google colab environment.

you can find my code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1L_vt6k0EQZZf92w0TpdKCM_j7eeFh5JN)

Comment: Indeed. Sadly 3D rotation is not working with Google Colab.

Comment: Hi. Does anyone know if this is available in Google Colab now?

Answer (score 5):

Try plotly (python graphic libraries) [3D scatter plot](https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/).

Comment: found official example forplotly (although not specifically for 3d scatter): https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=MYqcrcKLO4xe

Comment: I went straight to the provided link and it was amazingly simple to implement and the 3D plot rotates!

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you cannot rotate 3D plots generated by *MatPlotlib* in Colab. Plotly is a better alternative.

However, you can use the `view_init` method to change the view. It has two parameters (`elev` for elevation and `azim` for azimuth angles) to set to rotate the axes. You will get a different viewpoint.

[By default](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html), the `view_init` is set as `azim=-60, elev=30`. The angles are specified in degrees.
In your code, change the values of `elev` and `azim` to something else before using the scatter method. An example that uses `ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=-120)` is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1 = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
z1 = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

x2 = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
y2 = np.random.randint(-10, 0, size=10)
z2 = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=-120)
ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1, c='b', marker='o', label='blue')
ax.scatter(x2, y2, z2, c='g', marker='D', label='green')

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')
plt.title("3D Scatter Plot Example")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: Modified plot with elev & azimuth]

**Note**:

1. `ax.view_init(elev=0, azim=60)`: A zero elevation makes the plot as if we are looking horizontally.
2. `ax.view_init(elev=-30, azim=60)`: A negative elevation inverts vertically.

[This figure](https://www.celestis.com/resources/faq/what-are-the-azimuth-and-elevation-of-a-satellite/) explains the meaning of azimuth and elevation better.
[image: Azimuth & Elevation]

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a 3D scatter plot in Google Colaboratory, you can follow these steps using the provided example:

Open the example notebook by clicking on the following link:

> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j4PF-wWU0bQa1BY9DSkrtkraJteRv82n#scrollTo=AFDAcAp9tKiy&line=107&uniqifier=1

Once you have the notebook open, you can scroll down to the section where the 3D scatter plot is created. In the provided example, it seems that the 3D scatter plot is generated around line 107.

To rotate the plot, click and drag your mouse cursor on the 3D scatter plot itself. This action should allow you to freely rotate the plot in any direction you desire.

Experiment with different rotations until you achieve the desired view of your 3D scatter plot.

That's it! You can interactively rotate the 3D scatter plot in Google Colaboratory using the mouse cursor, as demonstrated in the provided example notebook.